# ошибка NameError: name 'сursor' is not defined

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Вот код:

```
import telebot
import sqlite3

#bot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_niсkname = message.from_user.username

    add_new_user(user_id, user_niсkname)

def add_new_user(user_id, user_niсkname):
    print(user_id)

    connect = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_inf(
        id INTEGER,
        niсkname TEXT,
        warnings_on_real_moment INTEGER
    );""")

    connect.commit()

    #chek id
    cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM users_inf WHERE id = 'user_id'""")
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:

        #add values in table
        сursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users_inf(id, niсkname, warnings_on_real_moment) 
            VALUES(?, ?, ?);""", user_id, user_niсkname, 0)
        connect.commit()

        print('У нас новый пользователь его id: ' + str(user_id) + ' Также его ник: ' + str(user_niсkname))
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты что пытаешься сделать?\n Ты уже есть в базе!')
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Не похоже, что в данном коде будет такая ошибка. **PS,** `cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM users_inf WHERE id = 'user_id'""")` тут никогда не будет результата. **PPS.** используйте биндинги в запросах. **PPPS.** `сursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users_inf(id, niсkname, warnings_on_real_moment) VALUES(?, ?, ?);""", user_id, user_niсkname, 0)` тут должна быть ошибка, т.к. биндинги нужно передавать вторым параметром и в коллекции

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
сursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users_inf(id, niсkname, warnings_on_real_moment)
```

У вас в этой строке в названии переменной `сursor` первая буква - русская `с`, поэтому питон и не знает эту переменную, он знает только нормальный `cursor` полностью из английских букв, а эта переменная с русской буквой не была ранее определена, а вы в этой строке пытаетесь её использовать.

Проверим, что буква не английская:

```
for i in 'сursor.execute("""INSERT INTO ':
    print(ord(i))
```

Вывод:

```
1089
117
114
115
111
114
46
...
```

Видите - код первой буквы совсем из другого диапазона. Это русская буква `с`, а не английская `c`.